# How to have two max file size limits on one Magento site

Tags: php, magento, file-upload, filesize

So here's my problem. In the admin section of our Magento site, we need the ability upload files that can be anywhere from 2-500 MB's each. I've set my php.ini settings appropriately and all is well with this requirement. But now I've been asked to allow guests to upload files from the front-end. Obviously, I do not want to give total strangers the ability to upload 500 MB files. I've searched around and have been unable to find a decent straight-forward answer to this problem.

So how do you allow your admin's to continue uploading extremely large files while restricting front-end users to a smaller file size?

Here's my current solution:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $helper = Mage::helper('my_module');
    if ( $post ) {
        try {
            if ($_FILES['size'] >= 2000000) { // Limit is set to 2 MB
                $errors[] = $helper->__('You have exceeded the max file size.');
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            // Perform save operations here.
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/*');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This checks to see if the file exceeds the limit. If it does, it throws an exception.

I realize that this solution is simple which is why I'm asking around if anyone has a better/alternative solution. I look forward to reading your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add an Observer to the event `controller_action_predispatch` and from there catch only POST send to controllers extending `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

This way you will get every files posted on any action, and would not have to redo the same job again and again. And the bonus is, when using observers, your are not messing with the Core of Magento.

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bdotenoitdotbe_Module>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </Bdotenoitdotbe_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <bdotenoitdotbe_module>
                <class>Bdotenoitdotbe_Module_Model</class>
            </bdotenoitdotbe_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <bdotenoitdotbe_module_controller_action_predispatch>
                        <class>bdotenoitdotbe_module/observer</class>
                        <method>parseFiles</method>
                    </bdotenoitdotbe_module_controller_action_predispatch>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Bdotenoitdotbe_Module_Model_Observer {
    const MAX_FRONTEND_UPLOAD_SIZE = 2000000;

    public function parseFiles($observer){
        if($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction() instanceof Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action &&
            $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            foreach($_FILES as $file_key => $file) {
                if($file['size'] > self::MAX_FRONTEND_UPLOAD_SIZE) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('File too big : '.$file['name']);
                    /**
                     * you can do unset($_FILES[$file_key]);
                     * but I would rather do the following to simulate a file too big behaviour
                     */

                    $file['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE;
                    $file['tmp_name'] = null;
                    $file['size'] = 0;
                    $_FILES[$file_key] = $file;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another interesting answer. I like the idea of creating my own observer which universally handles all file posts for the module you are hooked to. I'm going to give this a shot and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

upload_max_filesize is PHP_INI_PERDIR entry. This mean what this value can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3). You can't use ini_set in php file for this. 
Not sure about Apache, but here is how-to for Nginx:

1. set upload_max_filesize=10M in php.ini
2. add next lines in Nginx config inside `location ~ \.php$` block

   ```
   if ($request_uri ~ /admin/){
       client_max_body_size 500m;
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if ($request_uri ~ /admin/) {
       fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 500M \n post_max_size=500M";
   }
   ```

   Note: /admin/ is value from admin > routes > adminhtml > args > frontName in magento_root/app/etc/local.xml
3. restart Nginx

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't realize that you could set specific directories for the upload_max_filesize. I'm going to try that out and see how it works.